# Changing Schema on Line Work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, cad, schema-locks

I'm working on an engineering project in which the customer wants a CAD and GIS deliverable. The customer sent detailed examples of the schema for all line, point and polygon files delivered in their GIS component.

CAD doesn't attribute their features, so when I pull it into ArcMap it's schema is essentially blank. How do I take a line, polygon, point, etc. pulled into ArcMap from CAD and force a schema on it so I can begin filling in the attribute data? It would take extremely long if I had to create the features with correct schema and trace the linework.

Comment: What CAD software, and which version of ArcMap?  You could batch or script your schema onto your new feature classes, and then attribute them.

Comment: AutoCAD 2014 and ArcMap 10.3.1. Can you go into more detail regarding batching and scripting and possible point me in the right direction?